# TortoiseSVN extremely slow on commit

Tags: tortoisesvn

When using TortoiseSVN to commit it is extremely slow, about 3 kB/s. I've made one change which is adding a 200MB file to the working copy. The working copy contains 245 Files, 114 Folders. I have disabled the anti-virus and backup software. I have turned off the icon overlays. Checkout using TortoiseSVN is very fast as expected, between 500kB/s - 800kB/s. I've looked through many threads on this but usually they haven't checked the command line client or both are slow. Any ideas how to speed this up ?

When using the command line svn client both commit and checkout are quite fast, it doesn't display the connection speed so I can't tell for sure but a 200MB file commit takes between 5-10 minutes or so. Is there an option to get svn to show connection speed or even some kind of progress indicator ?

The server is RHEL, my computer is Win7 32-bit. The server is located in another country but is on the same internal network. I'm connecting using svn+shh with both TortoiseSVN and the command line client.

Thanks.

Comment: Who works on server side? What about firewalls on both sides? You miss almost *all useful information* - server OS, your OS, protocol, commit size and file-count, presence of post-commit hooks, speed of commit for **any other repository on  another server**. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458394/why-is-tortoisesvn-so-slow

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've done the recommended changes detailed on that page but they have no effect. I've not tried any other repository on another server as I don't have write access to any other one. However, using the svn command line client on the same repository and the same server works fine and very fast which would suggest that the server is configured fine. I've updated the question with more details as you requested. Any other information required or thoughts ?

Comment: Are you on the latest version of tortoise? Older versions of Tortoise do not always report the correct speed for uploads and downloads. Did your files transfer in the end?

Comment: Yes I'm on the most current version:

TortoiseSVN 1.7.1, Build 22161 - 32 Bit , 2011/10/21 22:51:59
Subversion 1.7.1, 
apr 1.4.5
apr-utils 1.3.12
neon 0.29.6
OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
zlib 1.2.5

After waiting for about 30mins and seeing no increase in speed I cancelled. With the command line client it takes no more than 10 minutes typically for a 200MB file so after 30 mins I figured it was going to speed up at all.

Comment: I've since tried using SmartSVN and this is faster. It uploads at between 50kB/s and 100kB/s. This is still quite a bit slower than the command line but miles better than TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Just an update, and also to clarify a bit about the command line usage. When using the command line I'm using OpenSSH. When I switched this to using plink.exe (which TortoiseSVN uses) it slowed by a factor of 5. This is still miles faster than when using the GUI. When I tried to get TortoiseSVN to use OpenSSH it wouldn't work at all. If I could get this to work it would be interesting to see the performance.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the same slowliness with TortoiseSVN (32 bits on Windows XP) over the svn+ssh:// protocol whatever we use: Repository Browser, checkout, commit...

So it seems to be related to the protocol itself because https works well for the same repository. It may come from inconsistent OpenSSL or SSH versions between TortoiseSVN and the server. You should try with an updated RHEL server.

Until it is fixed, I recommend to stay on TortoiseSVN 1.6.16 as far as the svn+ssh:// protocol is used/required.

Comment: I updated TortoiseSVN to the latest version as I had seen the same speed problem on 1.6 and I knew that the first thing people would suggest is to use the latest version. I don't think client vs server version is an issue to be honest, don't they just use a standard protocol ? We are looking into it at the network level at the moment to see the behaviour of TSVN for the svn command line to determine what is slowing it down. We are also considering a local svn mirror.

Comment: It depends the way you access your repository. They are 4 ways indeed. With http/https, protocol is almost standard, based on WebDAV. The "svn://" protocol is specific and may be tunneled over ssh. By the way these protocols have not changed between 1.6 and 1.7. You may also have troubles with TortoiseSVN Cache backgroup process on your workstation.